# Editing text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a text editor where I have two texts that I want to modify, so I made the code below but it ends up not changing anything, I would like to know what I should change to make it work editing one at a time

I'm doing this without using any package (text editing like flutter_quill)

What I hope is that it 'underlines' only the text in the selected container

//View

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter_mobx/flutter_mobx.dart';
 import 'editing_state.dart';

class EditingView extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditingView({super.key});

  @override
  State<EditingView> createState() => _EditingViewState();
}

class _EditingViewState extends State<EditingView> {

  final stateView = EditingState();

  final GlobalKey _formKey = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey _formKey2 = GlobalKey();

  TextDecoration? textDecoration;
  int selectedIndex = 1;

  final postItController = TextEditingController();
  final postItController2 = TextEditingController();

final Map<String, int> fontTextDecorationMap = {
  'None': 0,
  'Underline': 1,
};

final Map<String, List> formulasTextDecoration= {
  '0': [TextDecoration.none],
  '1': [TextDecoration.underline],
};

  List<TextDecoration> fontListTextDecoration = [
    TextDecoration.none,
    TextDecoration.none
  ];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

void changeTextDecoration(textDecoration) {
      int? font = fontTextDecorationMap[textDecoration];
      var resultado = formulasTextDecoration[font.toString()]?[0];

      for(int i = 0; i < fontList.length; i ++){
        if (selectedIndex == 1) {
          fontListTextDecoration[i + 1] = resultado;
        } else {
          fontListTextDecoration[selectedIndex] = resultado;    
        }
      }
    }
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar( title: 'Editing'),
    body: Column(
        children: [ 
            Container(
                height: 50, 
                color:Color(0xFFEBEEF3),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Row(
                    children: [
                        Observer( 
                            return GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){ 
                                    textDecoration = TextDecoration.underline;
                                    changeTextDecoration(textDecoration); 
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)), 
                                                color: stateView.highlight ? Colors.transparent : const Color(0x5FA1BFF8), 
                                           ), 
                                           child: Icon(  Icons.format_underline, color: stateView.highlight ? const Color(0xFF1F3359) : const Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 33, 56), 
                                            ), 
                                        ), 
                                ); 
                            } 
                        ], 
                    ]
                ), 
             ),
            GestureDetector( 
                onTap: () { 
                    setState(() { 
                        selectedIndex = 0; 
                    }); 
                }, 
                Container( 
                    height: 300, 
                    width: 300, 
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15), 
                    decoration: 
                        BoxDecoration( 
                            color: Colors.red, 
                            boxShadow: const [ 
                                BoxShadow( 
                                    color: Color(0x3CC2C2C2), 
                                    offset: Offset(5, 5), 
                                    blurRadius: 2, 
                                    spreadRadius: 0.01, 
                                ), 
                            ], 
                       ), 
                    child: Form( 
                        key: _formKey, 
                        child: TextFormField( 
                            controller: postItController, 
                            style: TextStyle( 
                                decoration: fontListTextDecoration[0], 
                            ), 
                        ), 
                    ), 
                ), 
             }
             GestureDetector( 
                onTap: () { 
                    setState(() { 
                        selectedIndex = 0; 
                    }); 
                }, 
                Container( 
                    height: 300, 
                    width: 300, 
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15), 
                    decoration: 
                        BoxDecoration( 
                            color: Colors.blue, 
                            boxShadow: const [ 
                                BoxShadow( 
                                    color: Color(0x3CC2C2C2), 
                                    offset: Offset(5, 5), 
                                    blurRadius: 2, 
                                    spreadRadius: 0.01, 
                                ), 
                            ], 
                       ), 
                    child: Form( 
                        key: _formKey2, 
                        child: TextFormField( 
                            controller: postItController2, 
                            style: TextStyle( 
                                decoration: fontListTextDecoration[1], 
                            ), 
                        ), 
                    ), 
                ), 
             }
           ],
         ),
      );
    }
```

```
//State

    import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';

    part 'editing_state.g.dart';

    class EditingState = _EditingState with _$EditingState;
    
    abstract class _EditingState with Store {
    
    @observable
    bool _highlight  = true;
    
    @computed
    bool get highlight  => _highlight ;
    
    @action
    void changeHighlight() {
    _highlight  = !_highlight ;
    }
    
    @action
    void resetState() {
    _highlight = true;
    }
    }
```

//editing_state.g.dart

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'editing_state.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// StoreGenerator
// **************************************************************************

// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names, unnecessary_brace_in_string_interps, unnecessary_lambdas, prefer_expression_function_bodies, lines_longer_than_80_chars, avoid_as, avoid_annotating_with_dynamic, no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers

mixin _$EditingState on _EditingState, Store {
  Computed<bool>? _$highlightComputed;

  @override
  bool get highlight=> (_$highlightComputed ??=
          Computed<bool>(() => super.highlight, name: '_EditingState.highlight'))
      .value;

  late final _$_highlightAtom =
      Atom(name: '_EditingState._highlight', context: context);

  @override
  bool get _highlight {
    _$_highlightAtom.reportRead();
    return super._highlight;
  }

  @override
  set _highlight(bool value) {
    _$_highlightAtom.reportWrite(value, super._highlight, () {
      super._highlight = value;
    });
  }

  late final _$_EditingStateActionController =
      ActionController(name: '_EditingState', context: context);

  @override
  void changeHighlight() {
    final _$actionInfo = _$_EditingStateActionController.startAction(
        name: '_EditingState.changeHighlight');
    try {
      return super.changeHighlight();
    } finally {
      _$_EditingStateActionController.endAction(_$actionInfo);
    }
  }

  @override
  void resetState() {
    final _$actionInfo = _$_EditingStateActionController.startAction(
        name: '_EditingState.resetState');
    try {
      return super.resetState();
    } finally {
      _$_EditingStateActionController.endAction(_$actionInfo);
    }
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '''
highlight: ${highlight}
    ''';
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share  reproducible code to try. your code block is not working

Comment: I edited the post, would that be it?

Comment: At what point do you call `setState` with any of your edits? Also, you say you are doing this without packages, but the second line of your code has you importing MobX.

Comment: In the first Gesture, when I say without using package I am referring to packages that already exist for text editing such as flutter_quill